# wso-wsf php Fatal error: Class 'WSService' not found

Tags: php, apache2, wso2

Once upon a time my apache+php+wso/wsf-php were all happily working. A bad day I had to restart the apache2 server and from that point on every time my php code creates WSService or WSClient, apache returns "class not found".

From /var/log/apache2/error.log the problem is
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: wsf: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
in Unknown on line 0

Then I tried (several times) to recompile the wsf-php framework following its README, but it creates the following dir: /usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs
and already from the dir name you can see the wrong version.

What should I do to use wso-wsf php working again?

Additional infos:
gcc (Debian 4.6.3-1) 4.6.3
PHP 5.4.0-3 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2012 07:59:57)
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

Thanks and Ciao,
Marco

Comment: So where is the correct compiled module located and how does your http.conf look like at the moment?

Comment: I tried to resume the old version of the module searching it using `find` but with the module I've found in a trash folder I still have the same error. I think maybe the old version has been deleted/substituted. The httpd.conf does not talk about wsf. It has a few lines for mod_proxy and bugzilla, nothing more.

Comment: sorry, I meant php.ini (not httpd.conf)

Comment: php.ini has a wsf section with wsf.home=<path_to_wsf.so_dir>, extension_dir=<wsf.home>, extension=wsf.so and wsf.log_path=/var/log/apache2

Comment: hm, so there is configuration missing, but I think we have another problem a step ahead. I am assuming that you compiled it like this:

$ cd extname
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
# make install

where "extname" is the wsf extension. Check out the first comment here, maybe this fixes your problem: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php

Comment: Thank you very much! The first comment highlights the problem. I've detected 3 `php-config` using `find / -iname php-conf*` and they all say that the api version is 20060613+lfs. But phpinfo() returns `PHP API 20100412` and the log file says that it is 20100525...

Comment: run phpinfo() in the browser. Check out which php.ini is used by Apache (mod_php). Then use this php.ini when you compile the wsf module as outlined in the comment in the manual

Comment: I recompiled the module with `./configure --with-php-ini=<path/php.ini>` according to phpinfo() output but it does not solve the issue. :(

Comment: After "make install" the .so file should be in the extension_dir listed in phpinfo(). Can you confirm this? And - just to be sure: you restarted Apache, right?

Comment: yes, wsf.so is in extension_dir and I can confirm it because both I explicitly set that dir in the php.ini file and also from the phpinfo() I can see that the var points to the same location as in php.ini. Just to be sure I do the following: (1) `tar -xvzf wsf.tar.gz` and goto the new wsf dir (2) ./configure (3) make (4) make install (5) check if the new wsf.so in the correct dir wrt php.ini (6) `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` (7) `tail <path>error.log`

Comment: I am missing the phpize command in your list. http://phpize.net/

Comment: Thanks jamie for your help in this endurance against wsf-php :)

This because if I follow the instruction (wso2-wsf-php-src-2.1.0/README.INSTALL) I don't have to do it. But I also installed it from src folder using phpize and it returns the same error. Anyway I've noticed that running `php` from shell it uses a different php.ini wrt the one used in phpinfo().

Comment: Sorry, I am running out of ideas. :-(

Comment: just a last idea: try to complete the installation next and see what happens. By "completing" I mean all the other steps as outlined in the manual, like setting the path, configuring php.ini...

Comment: I've installed the needed php version (with api 20100525) on another machine and than I've compiled wsf-php. I've copied the module on the server and the error is gone!!! unfortunately I now have ` PHP Fatal error:  WSService::__construct(): error creating service in path/file.php`

Comment: I had to copy the wsf_c dir in the server in order to let the php.ini (wsf.home entry) point to the correct location. Now the problem is that when I create a wsservice/client object it creates a null object...